# selecting the un-used connecter and harness supports in Catia electrical harness in vb scripting

Tags: vba, catia

I am trying to create macro that can select the components which are not used to route wire  and delete it or hide it[reference image][1].[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmqfL.png

you can see in image XML.3 and CONT.3 not connected to wire. Now i want to delete both components.so I can eliminate the useless components in my ASSY . to be honesty i don't have any idea how to proceed with it.

Comment: What code have your tried?  Have you checked the documentation if these objects have a method to check the connection state? How do you check this manual?

Comment: i did not got any way to check that. not sure how to initiate

Comment: Maybe you could use a clash as a workaround. So you could delete all products which don't overlap with other products.